# How would I add a delay to this JQuery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an event that appends some html:

```
   $("#feed").live("mouseover", function(){
       $("#main").append('<div class="help_div" id="feed_help"><p>Your feed shows you information on the users you follow, such as songs added, voting, commenting, following, and the showing of songs between users.</p></div><div class="arrow" id="feed_arrow"></div>');
    });
```

How would I cause there to be a 2000 millisecond gap between mousing over the selected element and appending the html?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll use a timeout.

```
$("#feed")
    .live("mouseover", function() {
        $(this).data("timeout", setTimeout(function() {
            $("#main").append('<div class="help_div" id="feed_help"><p>Your feed shows you information on the users you follow, such as songs added, voting, commenting, following, and the showing of songs between users.</p></div><div class="arrow" id="feed_arrow"></div>');    
        }, 2000));
    });
```

That will wait 2 seconds before running the code but if you move the mouse out of the element it will still show up 2 seconds later. So what you do is that you add a clearTimeout event. That will make sure that the timeout doesn't *tick* if you're not hovering.

```
$("#feed")
    .live("mouseout", function() {
        var timer = $(this).data("timeout");
        if (timer)
            clearTimeout(timer);
    });
```

Comment: @Alnitak, Can you please explain, why using .data to store the timer handle, is a good thing?

Comment: @Starx because it allows each element to have its own timer stored right with it, rather than having to track a whole load of JS variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [delay method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

This method was added in JQuery 1.4
Using this, your code will become:

```
$("#feed").live("mouseover", function(){
       $("#main").delay(2000).append('<div class="help_div" id="feed_help"><p>Your feed shows you information on the users you follow, such as songs added, voting, commenting, following, and the showing of songs between users.</p></div><div class="arrow" id="feed_arrow"></div>');
    });
```